# Azure API Management - User Metadata

Tags: azure-api-management, api-gateway

I am using Azure API Management to provide API gateway for some APIs. To set up a policy for a particular Api, I have used a Property(Named Value) to restore user metadata and then I assign it into a Variable in incoming request body. When adding a new user I need to add metadata for the new user in to the json. The property value has grown and exceeded the limit now and I cannot add more info to it anymore. I am wondering what the best way is to restore my large metadata in order to be accessible in API Management policy?

**Update1**:

I have switched the Authentication process from Azure to Auth0 so I can add the user metadata to Auth0 app_metadata and then in Azure policies I validate JWT from Auth0 and obtain token claim(app_metadata) explained in [this article](http://devjourney.com/blog/2017/03/23/extract-jwt-claims-in-azure-api-management-policy/). By doing so I can solve the large user metadata (json) issue however this doesn't solve other non-related user metadata stored in other Properties(Named Value) and moreover the API gateway inbound policies are growing and becoming a huge bunch of logic which is not easy to manage and maintain.

At this stage I am looking for a solution to handle all the API gateway inbound policies in a better way and more manageable environment i.e. C#. So my two cents is to implement the API gateway inbound policies in a new .net Api and call this new API in the existing API gateway inbound policies so that it can play a bridge role between Azure API gateway and existing API however I'm still not sure if this is acheivable and whether existing API can be called via new API directly or it should be called via Azure API gateway in some way!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I ended up with [this solution](https://anthonychu.ca/post/azure-api-management-look-up-user-cosmos-db/) which basically suggests to restore user metadata in Azure Cosmos DB and call Cosmos API in API Management Policy to access to the metadata and also the Cosmos API call can be cached in the policy.

Answer (score 0):

At this point you have to either store it in multiple variables or hardcode it in policy directly.

Comment: that's a work around that I already thought about it too and it is only good for very urgent case as a quick terrible solution.